# Using the uber api as an expense provider

Tags: uber-api

I would like to know what would be the integration like to become as a expense provider  for Uber? This would be mobile apps along with web.

Cheers!

Answer (score 1):

From an API perspective, aggregating of receipts that would be necessary for an expense provider is not allowed. If the users called the rides through your app, however, that is allowed. See the description here:

https://developer.uber.com/docs/ride-requests/guides/scopes
"request_receipt - this is only granted to apps that request Uber rides directly and show receipts as part of the trip lifecycle. We do not allow apps to aggregate receipt information."

Beyond the API and looking at an integration into the Uber app directly, there are a few large expense providers integrated. This is described here: https://newsroom.uber.com/auto-expense/. I do not believe they are adding more integrations there, but if you work for a large expense provider company like Concur it might be worth engaging via your business department.

Hope that helps!